# Pytorch forward hook on FCN-ResNet50 architecture

Tags: python, pytorch

I am using the FCN-Resnet50 model from Pytorch framework and I would like to extract the features vector of one layer using the `register_forward_hook` function.
I am using the following code to load the model.

```
import torch
model = torch.hub.load("pytorch/vision:v0.10.0", "fcn_resnet50", pretrained=True)
model.eval()
```

Using the following code gives me the names of each layer.

```
for _item in model.named_modules():
    print(_item)
```

The layer that I am interested in is the fourth layer of the backbone which is defined as below.

```
('backbone.layer4.2.conv1', Conv2d(2048, 512, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False))
('backbone.layer4.2.bn1', BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True))
('backbone.layer4.2.conv2', Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(4, 4), dilation=(4, 4), bias=False))
('backbone.layer4.2.bn2', BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True))
('backbone.layer4.2.conv3', Conv2d(512, 2048, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False))
('backbone.layer4.2.bn3', BatchNorm2d(2048, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True))
('backbone.layer4.2.relu', ReLU(inplace=True))
```

I am using the following function to register the forward hook and to get the feature vector of one of the last layer (ReLU).

```
def get_features_vector(_path_img, _model, _layer) -> torch.Tensor:
    """
    Input:
        path_img: string, /path/to/image
        _model: a pretrained torch model
    Output:
        my_output: torch.tensor, output of last convolution layer
    """
    input_image = Image.open(_path_img)
    preprocess = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(),
                                     transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
                                                          std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])])

    input_tensor = preprocess(input_image)
    input_batch = input_tensor.unsqueeze(0)

    with torch.no_grad():
        my_output = None

        def my_hook(module_, input_, output_):
            print(f"Output Shape: {output_.shape}")
            nonlocal my_output
            my_output = output_

        a_hook = _layer.register_forward_hook(my_hook)

        _model(input_batch)
        a_hook.remove()
        return my_output
```

And I am using the following code to extract the feature vector.

```
_feature_vector = get_features_vector(path_to_image, model, model.backbone.layer4[2].relu)
```

The problem I am having is that about the `print` output inside the `my_hook` nested function as it is:

```
Output Shape: torch.Size([1, 512, 60, 80])
Output Shape: torch.Size([1, 512, 60, 80])
Output Shape: torch.Size([1, 2048, 60, 80])
```

I don't understand why I am getting three lines as I am expecting only one.
Please help.

Comment: When you register the forward hook on model.backbone.layer4[2].relu, it is called for every layer in the block, so you see three output shapes. To get the output of the last convolutional layer in the block, you should be modify your forward hook to only record the output of the last convolutional layer in the block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the call to the function `get_features_vector` to the following gives a single print output.

```
_feature_vector = get_features_vector(path_to_image, model, model.backbone.layer4[2])
```